# LC3 Assembly Language: How would I check user input for invalid input

Tags: assembly, lc3

Currently, I am able to have the user input a signed multi-digit number (max of 5) such as +7246 or -14237 which will return to the designated register (R4 in this case) as x1C4E or xC863.

But I also want to have it so when the user enters an invalid input such as two sign's (++ or --) or nothing or an internal invalid character it will output an ERROR message and have the user try again. How would I do this?

```
.ORIG x3000     
;-------------
;Instructions
;-------------
RESET_PROGRAM

ADD R4,R4, #0
LD R1, COUNT
LD R2, MAX

; output intro prompt
LD R0, introPromptPtr
PUTS

; Set up flags, counters, accumulators as needed
POSITIVE     .STRINGZ "+"
NEGATIVE     .STRINGZ "-"
NEWLINE .STRINGZ "\n"
COUNT   .FILL #5
MAX  .FILL #9
RESET   .FILL #0

; Get first character, test for '\n', '+', '-', digit/non-digit     
GETC 

BR nineCHECK_0
END_nineCHECK_0
BR zeroCHECK_0
END_zeroCHECK_0

ADD R5,R0,#0

;R0 = -45(decimal) = -(ASCII)
ADD R0,R0,#-15 
ADD R0,R0, #-15
ADD R0, R0, #-15
BRz IS_NEGATIVE
ADD R0,R0,#2
Brz POSITIVE_ADD
BR IS_POSITIVE

IS_POSITIVE; is it = '+'? if so, ignore it, go get digits
    LEA R0,RESET
    ADD R0,R5,#0
    OUT
    ADD R4,R0,#0
    ;R5 = -48(decimal) = 0(ASCII)
    ADD R4,R4, #-12
    ADD R4,R4, #-12
    ADD R4,R4, #-12
    ADD R4,R4, #-12

    ADD R1,R1,#-1
    RETURN1

POSITIVE_LOOP    ;5 max loop
    GETC
    OUT
    BR nineCHECK_1
    END_nineCHECK_1
    BR zeroCHECK_1
    END_zeroCHECK_1
    
    ADD R3,R0, #0    ;if NEWLINE, end loop
    ADD R3,R3, #-10
    BRz POSITIVE_ENTER_OUT   
    
    ADD R0,R0, #-12
    ADD R0,R0, #-12
    ADD R0,R0, #-12
    ADD R0,R0, #-12

    ADD R6,R4, #0
    
    MULTIPLY_POSITIVE
        ADD R4,R4,R6
        ADD R2,R2, #-1
        BRp MULTIPLY_POSITIVE
        
    ADD R4,R4,R0
    
    LD R2,MAX
    ADD R1,R1, #-1
    BRp POSITIVE_LOOP
    
    HALT
    
POSITIVE_ENTER_OUT

HALT

IS_NEGATIVE; is it = '-'? if so, set neg flag, go get digits
    LEA R0,NEGATIVE
    PUTS
    
    NEGATIVE_LOOP ;5 num loop
        GETC
        OUT
        
    BR nineCHECK_2
    END_nineCHECK_2
    BR zeroCHECK_2
    END_zeroCHECK_2
        
        ADD R3,R0, #0
        ADD R3,R3, #-10
        BRz NEGATIVE_ENTER_OUT
        
        ADD R0,R0, #-12
        ADD R0,R0, #-12
        ADD R0,R0, #-12
        ADD R0,R0, #-12

        ADD R6,R4, #0
        
        MULTIPLY_NEGATIVE
            ADD R4,R4,R6    ;by 10
            ADD R2,R2, #-1
            BRp MULTIPLY_NEGATIVE
            
        ADD R4, R4, R0
        
        LD R2, MAX
        ADD R1,R1, #-1
        BRp NEGATIVE_LOOP
        
        NOT R4,R4   ;Two's complement
        ADD R4,R4, #1
        
        HALT
    NEGATIVE_ENTER_OUT
    
    NOT R4,R4
    ADD R4,R4, #1
    
    HALT
    
POSITIVE_ADD
    LEA R0,POSITIVE
    PUTS
    BR RETURN1
    
nineCHECK_0
  ADD R7, R0, #0
  LD R6, MAX

  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  NOT R6, R6
  ADD R6, R6, #1

  ADD R6, R7, R6
  BRp ERROR_STATE
BR END_nineCHECK_0


nineCHECK_1
  ADD R7, R0, #0
  LD R6, MAX

  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  NOT R6, R6
  ADD R6, R6, #1

  ADD R6, R7, R6
  BRp ERROR_STATE
BR END_nineCHECK_1



nineCHECK_2
  ADD R7, R0, #0
  LD R6, MAX

  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12       
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  NOT R6, R6
  ADD R6, R6, #1

  ADD R6, R7, R6
  BRp ERROR_STATE
BR END_nineCHECK_2

zeroCHECK_0
  ADD R7, R0, #0
  LD R6, RESET

  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  NOT R6, R6
  ADD R6, R6, #1

  ADD R6, R7, R6
  BRn ERROR_STATE
BR END_zeroCHECK_0


zeroCHECK_1
  ADD R7, R0, #0
  LD R6, RESET

  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  NOT R6, R6
  ADD R6, R6, #1

  ADD R6, R7, R6
  BRn ERROR_STATE
BR END_zeroCHECK_1

zeroCHECK_2
  ADD R7, R0, #0
  LD R6, RESET

  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  ADD R6, R6, #12
  NOT R6, R6
  ADD R6, R6, #1

  ADD R6, R7, R6
  BRn ERROR_STATE
BR END_zeroCHECK_2



ERROR_STATE
  LD R0, errorMessagePtr
  PUTS

  LD R0, NEWLINE
  PUTS

BR RESET_PROGRAM

; remember to end with a newline!
LD R0,NEWLINE
PUTS
                    
HALT

;---------------    
; Program Data
;---------------

introPromptPtr  .FILL xB000
errorMessagePtr .FILL xB200

.END

;------------
; Remote data
;------------
.ORIG xB000  ; intro prompt
INTRO_MSG .STRINGZ   "Input a positive or negative decimal number (max 5 digits), followed by ENTER\n"

.END                    
                    
.ORIG xB200  ; error message
ERROR_MSG .STRINGZ   "ERROR: invalid input\n"

;---------------
; END of PROGRAM
;---------------
.END
```

[Black ?s error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNfp4.png)

Comment: Just do a range check. Which part is causing you problem?

Comment: I'm assuming it would have it be in the one of the CHECKs but not sure what the range check would look like

Comment: Your code is not commented and hard to follow. On closer look your `CHECK` (three copies???) already seem to be doing the check for `<= 9` so you just need the `>= 0` and make sure they are invoked in the correct places.

Comment: I needed 3 CHECK copies bc I was getting a label error. I guess because I couldn't use the same check more than once? Anyways, for >=0 I assume it would be the same CHECK code but instead of R6=9 it would be 0 and then after adding 12 4 times I would get dec=48 which is char=0 and it would be BRn instead of BRp? And I would put the new check loop after the the other CHECK_0,1,2?

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right.

Comment: Of course you can merge the two checks by first subtracting the 48 and if that goes negative it's less than a `'0'`. Then you can subtract 9 and if it's still positive that means it's above `'9'`.

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting error msg outputted when I don't enter a full 5 digit number and I can't even put a + or - in the beginning. I have updated my code above with the new CHECK

Comment: Your newline check is **after** the digit check so that already detects the newline as invalid digit. Swap the order of the checks. Also you need to move the sign check up.

Comment: Also, `LD R0, NEWLINE` should be `LEA` but of course your `ERROR_MSG` already includes the newline so it's kind of pointless. Maybe you wanted to print the newline before the error?

Comment: Ok, I have swapped my NEWLINE and DIGIT checks and also moved my SIGN check up, but after outputing an error msg I'm getting weird output black ?s. I have attached a screenshot above. Also, I am unable to make it so the program can assume that the number is positive without the + sign. So 1234 would be a valid positive input.

Comment: The weird output is due to the `LD R0, NEWLINE` as I said.

Comment: That's weird because I did change 'LD R0, NEWLINE'  to LEA but now it is not outputting the error message string.